# How to Add hookups to Powershell script

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script called PostPro.ps1.I would like to provide a hookups to this script so 
   that if there is need one can add functionality before and after execution of PostPro.ps1 script.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Ramani

Answer (score 1):

another way with parameters :
postpro.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [ScriptBlock]$before,
   [ScriptBlock]$after
    )

if($before -ne $null){
Invoke-Command $before
}

write-host "hello"

if($after -ne $null){
Invoke-Command $after
}
```

then one can provide script to execute :

```
$b={write-host "before"}
$a={write-host 'after' }
PS>.\postpro.ps1 -before $b -after $a
before
hello
after
```

Answer (score -2):

One way to do this would be to use modules. If you put all of your extension functions in modules in a certain folder with a certain name format, and then each module needs a runBefore and a runAfter function.

In your PostPro.ps1 script you can load the modules like this:

```
$modules = ls $(Join-Path $hookDir "postPro-extension-*.psm1") | 
    % { import-Module $_.FullName -AsCustomObject }
```

This will load all of the files in $hookDir that have a name that looks like postPro-extension-doSomething.psm1. Each module will be stored in a object that will give you access to each modules functions. To run the functions you can just call them on each object as show below.

You can go like this before the main part of the script

```
$modules | % { $_.runBefore }
```

and this after the main part of the script

```
$module | % { $_.runAfter }
```

Comment: Can someone explain me how this can answer to the OP? and how can works??

Comment: It is a vague question so I don't know exactly what the requirements are. But this provides a way to run code before and after a script without modifying the script itself.

Comment: check this line: `$modules = ls Join-Path $hookDir "postPro-extension-*.psm1"`, please

Comment: Ah yes, I see the problem. I think I fixed it now